# How to make scrollable, resizable listview?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, scrollviewer

Originally I wanted to make listview dependant on window height parameter, but to be honest I find this solution impractical, believing it can be done better.

So, here is an object of my interest:

```
<StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LessonTitle}" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" FontSize="36" Background="DimGray"></TextBlock>
            <Grid Height="Auto" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                <ListView x:Name="LV2" Background="DimGray"
                          BorderBrush="Transparent"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Lessons}"
                       ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                      SizeChanged="LV2_SizeChanged">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Height="1000"
                                        ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
                                        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                                    <TextBlock Width="Auto" FontSize="24" Foreground="Black" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                                        <Run Text="{Binding LessonText}"/>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding LessonImage}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
```

My listview and remnants of several attempts to make it scrollable (also also resizable with the window), and by scrollable I mean to make an entire list scroll smoothly, instead of by each element, but I have no clue how to achieve it.

I've already tried changing stackpanels to dockpanels/grids and vice versa, different scrollviwer placements, but none of them work. At best what I could've achieved so far was either scrolling listview's first item or scrolling item by item.

UPDATE:

So far I seem to have achieved the desired result:

```
<StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LessonTitle}" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" FontSize="36" Background="DimGray"></TextBlock>
            
            <Grid Height="Auto">
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="SV" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" SizeChanged="SV_SizeChanged">
                <ListView x:Name="LV2" Background="DimGray"
                          BorderBrush="Transparent"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Lessons}"
                          Width="Auto" Height="Auto"
                          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Height="Auto">
                                <TextBlock Width="Auto" FontSize="24" Foreground="Black" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                                        <Run Text="{Binding LessonText}"/>
                                </TextBlock>
                                <Image Source="{Binding LessonImage}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
            
        </StackPanel>
```

This is how I did it in XAML, I've put an entire listview into a scrollviewer and made the size dependant on the window size throught this function:

```
private void SV_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      SV.Height = HeightModel.Instance.Height - 100;
      SV.Width = HeightModel.Instance.Width - 120;
    }
```

I also added width and height ot the listview.

However the size updates only upon changing the view and not in real time. So now I need help to make it actually responsive, either by making this function work in real time or purely throught XAML.

The other problem is that for some reason I cannot scroll the listview with mouse scholl, but only with mouse click, and I am completely confused why it happened to work like this.

Comment: StackPanel has infinite height. You may want to change to Grid and see if it helps.

Comment: Done so already with both, result was the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
<StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LessonTitle}" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" FontSize="36" Background="DimGray"></TextBlock>
            <Grid Height="Auto" >
                <ListBox x:Name="LV2" Width="400" Height="400" Background="DimGray"
                          BorderBrush="Transparent"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Lessons}"
                      SizeChanged="LV2_SizeChanged">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Height="1000">
                                    <TextBlock FontSize="24" Foreground="Black" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                                        <Run Text="{Binding LessonText}"/>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding LessonImage}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
```

[image: note the repeat buttons present on the box and not the view]

ListBox has these properties by default. just define the size of the visible area and everything extending beyond that comes scrollable.
You may want to separate the items to their own item slots instead of a stackpanel that extends far beyond the dimensions of its contents as well.
Here is an example:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LessonTitle}" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" FontSize="36" Background="DimGray"></TextBlock>
    <Grid Height="504" >
        <ListBox x:Name="LV2" Height="400" Background="DimGray" BorderBrush="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding Lessons}" Panel.ZIndex="1" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
                <TextBlock FontSize="24" Foreground="Black" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding LessonText}" />
                <Image Source="/Image2.png" Width="297" Height="498"/>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

[image: The result:]

Note that if Lessons is a class and has properties in it then the box will automatically add them when defined as the ItemssSource. Also Some controls won't allow you to manipulate the items beyond the scope of its privileges if it is inheriting from an itemssource, instead manipulate the source itself to change the items.

If you need to populate the list with a larger quantity of items the easiest way would be in the .cs / vb codebehind.
The C# would be something like:

```
var lessons = //the source of the items.
foreach(var item in lessons){ LV2.Items.Add((new Grid/Canvas/Panel{ Child/Children.Add/Content = item }));
```

If you require multiple types of parent controls add an if else loop to check the type and a foreach loop to handle the respective type

XAML

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox"/>
```

Codebehind

```
        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in typeof(SomeTypeClass).GetProperties())
        {
            StackPanel panel = new StackPanel();
            panel.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal;
            panel.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
            panel.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;

            var lbl = new TextBlock();
            lbl.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
            lbl.Text = propertyInfo.Name;
            lbl.ToolTip = "ToolTipStuff";
            lbl.Margin = mrgn;
            panel.Children.Add(lbl);
            var spcr = new Rectangle();
            spcr.Width = 25;
            spcr.Height = 15;
            panel.Children.Add(spcr);
    if(prop.GetType() == typeof(string)
    {
            var txtBx = new System.Windows.Controls.TextBox();
            panel.Children.Add(txtBx);
            txtBx.Text = "TextToTheRightOfPropertyName";
            txtBx.ToolTip = "DifferentToolTipStuff";

            var spcr2 = new Rectangle();
            spcr2.Width = 5;
            spcr2.Height = 5;
      // ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
            panel.Children.Add(spcr2);
            var mtxtBx = new TextBox();
            mtxtBx.Height = 15;
  // ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
            panel.Children.Add(mtxtBx);
    listBox.Items.Add(panel);
    }
    else if (prop.GetType() == typeof(AnotherTypeofVar)
    {
    //add the respective type of element to panel :
    }
                // ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
           
    
        }
```

alternate codebehind

```
listbox.ItemsSource = //The class or database containing the data
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't help. The items were only scrollable horizontally (instead of vertically, as I wanted it to), and if there are two items, list instantly hops to another item instead of scrolling down smoothly throught the entire contents of items.

Also second code snippet does not work at all, it just crashes the program.

Comment: if the items don't extend below the bottom of the listbox then there is nothing to scroll to that means even if your stackpanel extends below but there is nothing inside of it there is nothing to render so it wont scroll. Also it's not a snippet it's an example that needs modification on your part to implement for your needs. 
Listbox contains items, items contain controls/elements. if you put a bunch of controls/elements in one item then it wont scroll smoothly. If you put a 1000 unit high stackpanel in one item the item will be that high

Comment: Also i see the ScrollViewer properties are set on the elements but there is no scroll viewer? Try wrapping the Root element in a ScrollViewer.

Comment: Alright, it seems like I've achieved the way I wanted the list to scroll by putting listview into a scrollviewer like you said,, however I had to hardcode scrollviewer to 1000 pixels in width and height, so right now I have find a way to make it adjustable to window size.

Comment: glad you figured it out, did you try a listbox though? I added a snip of the icons of listbox and listview controls as seen in the vs toolbox to this answer. as for the resize you can bind the width/height properties to the window if that's the only element in the window or use the Stretch setting of the alignments to fill available space within it's parent and the parent would need to also be bound / clipped/ stretched to fill the available space in it's parent and so on up to the window.

Comment: can you explain what you mean with binding properties to the window? Cuz I think I've done that too, instead of using HeightModel.Instance.Height/Width I used this.ActualWidth/Height, but not only wasn't the element adjusting to the size, but it was sized incorrenctly, eventhough the values should be identical. As for the listbox, haven't tried it yet, but I will see what I can do with this. As for the rest I am not sure if I understand you right, I tried using vertical alignment for listview and scrollview, however the list still goes out of bounds (except for width).

Comment: <ScrollViewer Width/Height="{Binding ActualWidth/Height, ElementName=windowname }">
 or 
(scrollViewer.Width = scrollViewer.Parent as UIElement).Width;

Comment: That will be a bit more difficult, given my listview is in usercontrol binded to main window. Also they have to be exactly 100 (height) and 120 (width) pixels smaller than window's size.